# How to copy/crop text using pdfsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdfsharp

I want to copy some text or area with (x,y) from existing pdf and paste it to a new pdf.
i am using pdfsharp.how to do this?
can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract text, look at these threads:

[C# PDFSharp: Examples of how to strip text from PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591992/c-sharp-pdfsharp-examples-of-how-to-strip-text-from-pdf)

[C# Extract text from PDF using PdfSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141143/c-sharp-extract-text-from-pdf-using-pdfsharp)

If you want to extract an image of the page (or a part of it), look at this thread:

[Export PDF to JPG(s) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782942/export-pdf-to-jpgs-in-c-sharp)

Comment: can i do with cropbox or somthing else ? how to use it ?