# File conversion from any document to image

Tags: asp.net

Im doing a asp.net(c#) project where im required to read any document(pdf,word,spreadhseet) but in the end each page of the document should be converted to an image. I couldnt find any api realted to that. It would be helpful if anyone can suggest me with some. Code examples.

Also it would be nice if i can get any good links for the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no free tool can do this.. you need some commercial solution

Comment: isnt there any api like that of itextsharp and asppdf for pdf conversion.

Comment: Take a look at iTextSharp. It supports loading the PDF, and the codec namespace supports TIFF and PNG. I suspect this library (which is free) may work for you.

Comment: Our commments crossed in the air. Have you verified iTextSharp doesn't have the functions you need? Specifically the PngWriter and TiffWriter classes seem beneficial.

Comment: i have used itextsharp in prject for converting any file to pdf and interacting with pdf.

Comment: Using a c# wrapper to ghostscript is one solution. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782942/export-pdf-to-jpgs-in-c-sharp

Comment: As far as the "any document format" goes -- why not convert everything to pdf first, then use ghostscript to create images?

Comment: ghostscript is better because all other will not support pdf conversion very good. you first convert everything in pdf then use ghostscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ghost script library (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) to create an image for each page of a PDF file. There is an excellent code sample here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32274/How-To-Convert-PDF-to-Image-Using-Ghostscript-API.

If you want to create images for other file types, you should convert them to PDF first. For MS office files, you can use office automation. For example, for word files it would be best to use office automation as only MS would know to convert word to PDF correctly. However, office automation as its cons, they are all over the web. Anyway, we use it for some time in my team and it looks as it is working well.